# simple? ajax to not refresh page when button clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a local server running using Node.js at localhost:3000 and it runs a static html page which has a button.

When I click the button I want it to 'go' to 'localhost:3000/buttonClicked' but I don't actually want the html page to change at all. I have the server handling the GET request so the only problem is I don't want to move away from my localhost:3000 page.

So I want to go to localhost:3000/buttonClicked, have the server do what it does when user goes to that page(this part I've completed already), **but I don't actually want the user to move away from localhost:3000**

I think I can use AJAX to do this but I have no idea if it's difficult or how I would do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Send an AJAX request to the route /buttonClicked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, there is a function called `load` that'll do this for ya.

You can do `$('body').load( './buttonClicked' );`

Comment: i think he just wants the server action to run without updating the page.

Comment: Make ajax request on button click. If input type is submit  "return false" in js on  click.

Comment: Ah sorry, misunderstood! You can easily do this `$.get('/buttonClicked');` If you actually need to do something with whatever HTML is outputted inside the localhost:3000/buttonClick page, then you can add a callback like so:  `$.get('/buttonClicked', function(response) { console.log(response); });`